# Why would character or string be considered falsy in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

Hey guys been racking my brain and reading articles on this subject and everything I have read stated "some string" or "a" is considered truthy, but when I wrote a code to test an array to filter out falsy items it kept saying strings and characters are falsy. I do know how to fix this issue using .filter(Boolean) but would like to know why my code wouldn't work Here is my code

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  // Don't show a false ID to this bouncer
  var idVar = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<arr.length + 1;i++) 
  {
    
    if(arr[i] === false|| arr[i]===0 || arr[i]==="" || arr[i]===null || arr[i]===undefined || isNaN(arr[i]) === true)
      {
         alert(arr[i]);
      }
    else
      {
        idVar.push(arr[i]);
      }
  }
 alert(idVar + " is the only one");
}

bouncer([1,"some string"]);
```

Comment: To clarify, which comparison (etc.) are you questioning?

Comment: To check if `arr[i]` is falsy just doing this `if( arr[i] )` will suffice! `if(arr[i]) { truthy } else { falsy }`! Or using `NOT !` `if( ! arr[i] ) { falsy }`!

Answer (score 3):

The `isNaN(arr[i]) === true` is causing it to pass.  `"some string"` will be coerced to a Number and then isNaN will evaluate to true.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Examples

Answer (score 0):

For your case, **isNaN("some string")** will be **true**.

Try:

```
function filter(arr) {
  var filteredArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i]) {
      filteredArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return filteredArray;
}
```

Remember you can also replace

```
if (arr[i]) {
}
```

by

```
if (arr[i] == false) {
}
```

=== also compares for type of values.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the problem is with `isNaN(arr[i])`, because a string that can't be parsed as a number will be coerced to `NaN`. If you want to use `isNaN`, you should first test if it's a number. So replace

```
isNaN(arr[i]) === true
```

with:

```
(typeof arr[i] === 'number' && isNaN(arr[i]))
```

You can also use `Number.isNaN(arr[i])`. This doesn't coerce its argument to a number first, so it returns `false` if the argument isn't a number.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, I added that to the answer.